# Multiple custom-authorizers in aws api-gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, custom-authentication

Is it possible to use multiple custom-authorizers in API-gateway? Or how do other do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think. You need to write a custom lambda authorizer to define such custom logic.

But you can have different end points using different authorizers under the same Api.

Comment: I am searching for the way to have different authorizers for different endpoints under same API. Can you suggest me a link or the method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can have multiple authorizers in one API (with different endpoints).
i.e:
you can have,

```
GET /parameters => with custom authorizer 01
POST /parameters => with custom authorizer 02
```